# How to get details session information on sessions using Google Analytic API in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics

I'm creating a custom Analytic system using Google Analytic API.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

I'm following a reporting standard like I have shown in the following image.

[image]

Here I display all the data monthly. Sessions, page views and all.
When I use normal way to get data, i only get an object like that this :

> totalsForAllResults: { 'ga:sessions': '8109', 'ga:pageviews': '11480' }

I am following [this](https://flaviocopes.com/google-analytics-api-nodejs/) tutorials to get analytic data using Node.JS. And here is the object i'm passing to get data.

```
'start-date': '30daysAgo',
'end-date': 'today',
'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews'
```

Is there any way to get specific monthly data or filter these data monthly ? I searched and tried many ways and still no good. There's no good documentation on official google API doc also. Is it impossible to take like that ? But in google analytic dashboard, they are showing these data by months and even weeks. Please help me on this. Any sample code is also appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: add a filter and only look for month? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#segments

Comment: @DaImTo There's no good example of that. Have you done something like that ?